# How to repeat main method in java

Tags: repeat

My question is simple but the answer eludes me. I have looked up and down for this little bit of info and can't find it.

It's simple, I have a program with println text that I want to have repeated just once. what is the line of code to do this in the simplest way.

There are two lines of System.out.println that make up the static void main and I want it to just repeat itself just once so that there is double without me actually typing in a System.out.println() to put a space between the first set and then just typing in an exact copy of the first set of two lines.

Example:

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
System.out.println("I am Klinton");
System.out.println()
System.out.println("Hello World!");
System.out.println("I am Klinton");
```

I want to shrink this to just the first two lines and have the program repeat it once to achieve the same result.

Comment: Have you looked up loops and how to use them. For example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Comment: It's called a `for` loop

Comment: Optimize the loop away. `String msg = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), "Hello World!", "I am Klinton"); System.out.printf("%s%n%n%s%n", msg, msg);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop.

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("I am Klinton");
    System.out.println()
}
```

This will loop ten times. It starts at one with initializing a new variable i to 1, sets the termination to when I is no longer less than or equal to 10, and the increment to 1, so i will increase by 1 each time the loop runs..

Comment: I've tried that before and this doesn't work for me. My teacher showed us a different method that simply calls upon the first method when it reaches the end in order to make it repeat iteself.

Comment: Could you please post your entire code, as well as your teachers method.